# C++ priority queue in ascending order by specific method for objects

Tags: c++, priority-queue

Lets say I have the a class called `MyClass` and every MyClass object has a method called `xVal`. What I want is a priority queue of `MyClass` objects sorted in ascending order of `MyClass.xVal()`

So far I have this:

```
priority_queue<MyClass, vector<MyClass>, greater<MyClass>> queue;
```

Of course, it doesn't do what I expect.I complies but uses some random ordering for my objects. Would appreciate it if someone can point out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Write your own [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses) or a lambda and replace `greater<MyClass>` with it.

Comment: @NathanOliver How do I write a lambda for this and isn't there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't do what I expect'?  Does it even compile?

Comment: @NathanOliver: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) about lambdas.  Unfortunately there isn't a simpler way of doing this.  You wither overload your `operator >` to do what you want or you provide your own functor to the `priority_queue` that does what you want.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy What about it?

Comment: @NathanOliver  Does it compile?  It's difficult to find out what's wrong from an 'It doesn't do what I want', especially if we don't know if it even compiles.  The example at cppreference shows how to setup and use a lambda for ordering the queue.

Comment: @NathanOliver Can you give an example of how to give a functor to a priority queue?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy IDK. I'm not the OP

Comment: Sorry, Nathan.  @AlexSmith:  Check the examples

Comment: @AlexSmith There's an example in the [link provided by Michael](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue).

Comment: @NathanOliver if I overload the < operator in MyClass will it work?

Comment: Lambda are way beyond my level here

Comment: If you want greater than you might find `>` more helpful than `<`.

Comment: @AlexSmith  lambdas will make make your life so much easier....  You should get used to them.  Reproducing the cppreference example is all you need for now.  Overriding operator< will also work, but its logic must be inversed, for what you want to do, which may lead to other issues... I suggest you override operator > instead, and use std::greater, as in your code above.  Still, using a lambda is the best way to go, as it makes your intent crystal clear.

Answer (score 3):

The [CPP Reference link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) to Priority Queue provides that a priority queue can be defined as:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

Here, `T=MyClass` and `Container=std::vector<MyClass>`. The only thing that remains is `Compare` which as has been mentioned above can be implemented using either Lambdas or Functors. I'll show both:

Let's say the class is defined as shown below with `xVal()` method's return value as the sort key:

```
struct MyClass{
    int count;
    int key;
    int xVal() { return count; };
};
```

**Using Lambdas**

```
//  Lambda skeleton: [capture preferences](arguments){ body }
auto cmp = [](MyClass left, MyClass right) {return left.xVal() > right.xVal();};
std::priority_queue<MyClass, std::vector<MyClass>, decltype(cmp)> queue(cmp);
```

**Using a Functor**

```
struct CmpFunctor{
    bool operator()(MyClass left, MyClass right) const {
        return left.xVal() > right.xVal();
    }
};
auto cmp = CmpFunctor()
std::priority_queue<MyClass, std::vector<MyClass>, decltype(cmp)> queue(cmp);
```

Here is a [link](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efe50d90bc2e01cc) showing the running code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the `xVal()` method mentioned in the question, rather than invent `count`?