# How to find the minimum element in vector of pairs in c++?

Tags: c++

if vector is  <0,8> <0,3> <1,4> <2,9> <3,5>

Suppose minimum need to be found considering second key of pair value only,
here it will be 3.

output:
sample.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: sample.cpp:24:45: error: cannot convert ‘std::pair’ to ‘int’ in initialization int i1=*std::min_element(v.begin(),v.end());

Comment: How would you do it by hand?  Start there, turn that into pseudo code, and then covert that into actual code.

Comment: `std::min_element` with a lambda will solve this. Can you show your attempt?

Comment: sample.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sample.cpp:24:45: error: cannot convert ‘std::pair<int, int>’ to ‘int’ in initialization
  int i1 =*std::min_element(v.begin(),v.end()); // to find the minimum

Comment: you should add the code and the error message in your question. Code in comments is impossible to read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::min_element` and make it test only the second element.

Something like:

```cpp
std::get<1>(*std::min_element(begin(v), end(v), [](auto lhs, auto rhs) {
  return std::get<1>(lhs) < std::get<1>(rhs)
}));
```

I'm using `get` here because I don't know if you are using `std::pair`s or `std::tuple`s.

As it's still very small structures, no need to pass by `const&`.

Answer (score 4):

You could either do it by a handcrafted for-loop or using STL `std::min_element` using a lambda. The way you have used it above is incorrect. Here is the correct way:

```
auto v = std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>{{0,8},{0,3},{1,4},{2,9},{3,5}};
auto result = *std::min_element(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return lhs.second < rhs.second;    
    });
std::cout << result.first << " " << result.second  << std::endl; // 0 3
```

You can try this [online here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f839d166cb00a91) and maybe tinker to understand how the lambda works.
`std::min_element` will work correctly for native types the way you have used it, but for derived ones like `std::pair` with the custom condition of only picking the second, you need to supply the criteria via a lambda.
I'd recommend reading up on C++ lambdas - theyre extremely handy in general but especially when needing to supply a custom predicate like in your case! Here is another example: [C++ priority queue in ascending order by specific method for objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109569/c-priority-queue-in-ascending-order-by-specific-method-for-objects/53109989#53109989)

Answer (score 1):

So, the vector looks like this:

```
vector<pair <int, int> > items = { <0,8> <0,3> <1,4> <2,9> <3,5> };
```

We need to loop through the items to find the smallest second item. To do that:

```
int saveIndex = 0
//now we can loop through all of the items in the vector
for(int i = 1; i < items.size(); i++)
{
    if(items[saveIndex].second > items[i].second)
    {
        saveIndex = i;
    }
}

//the smallest second value will be found at
int smallestValue = items[saveIndex].second;
```